# Could not find safe_yaml-0.9.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler

Pushing to heroku:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.2
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
   Old: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Could not find safe_yaml-0.9.2 in any of the sources
   Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Could not find safe_yaml-0.9.2 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'pg'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
 GEM
 remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.12)
      activemodel (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
    activesupport (3.2.12)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.3)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    devise (2.2.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    font-awesome-rails (3.1.1.3)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    haml (4.0.3)
      tilt
    hike (1.2.2)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (3.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.0)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.6)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    nokogiri (1.5.9)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-pjax (0.7.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.3)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.12)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activerecord (= 3.2.12)
      activeresource (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.12)
    rails_admin (0.4.9)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.1, < 5)
      font-awesome-rails (~> 3.0)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 2.1, < 4)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 3.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.6)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 0.6)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)
    railties (3.2.12)
      actionpack (= 3.2.12)
      activesupport (= 3.2.12)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    remotipart (1.0.5)
    safe_yaml (0.9.2)
    sass (3.2.9)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.14)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  cancan
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  devise
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.12)
  rails_admin
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: We'll need `Gemfile.lock` too. Running `bundle update` might clear up the matter.

Comment: Added. It looks like safe.yaml 0.9.2 is on its own! I'll try an update..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

safe_yaml 0.9.2 got yanked.  You need to upgrade to 0.9.3

One way to do that is find in your Gemfile.lock the line that says `safe_yaml (0.9.2)` and change it to `safe_yaml (0.9.3)`, save it and then run `bundle`.